# Why do plotly charts not render in flexdashboard consistently?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I am creating a simple dashboard in R with FlexDashboard. After the first Plotly chart is rendered, no additional Plotly charts will render, but they will be written to the underlying HTML. Is there a way to use multiple Plotly charts in succession?

I have tried writing Plotly charts from both the Plotly R library syntax and through ggplot2 with the `ggplotly` function, but neither method changes the issue. This issue seems to also be true for several other interactive graphing libraries (e.g., d3tree) but not others (e.g., sunburstr and highchartR).

Here is a minimal and reproducible example written in R markdown:

````
---
title: "Flexboard issue"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
```



```{r include = F}
states <- map_data("state")
arrests <- USArrests
names(arrests) <- tolower(names(arrests))
arrests$region <- tolower(rownames(USArrests))

choro <- merge(states, arrests, sort = FALSE, by = "region")
choro <- choro[order(choro$order), ]

plot_map <- ggplot(choro, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = assault)) 


plot_line <- ggplot(arrests, aes(murder, urbanpop)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

### Plot1

```{r}
plot_map
```


### Plot2

```{r}
plot_line
```


### Plot3

```{r}
ggplotly(plot_line)
```

### Plot4

```{r}
ggplotly(plot_map)
```

### Plot5

#```{r}
ggplotly(plot_line)
```
````